# Converting lats and longs to centerpoint in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a angular 2 website using the Arcgis API 3.24.  I'm fairly new to ESRI and I was wondering how I could convert a extent that has values of

```
spatialReference :
    {wkid: 4326}
    xmax:
        "-106.477219"
    xmin :
        "-106.728864"
    ymax:
        "35.190922"
    ymin:
        "35.014214"
```

to a centerpoint x and y that I could center my map on?

My code:

```
setSelectedItem(selItem: any) {
  const self = this;
  loadModules(['esri/geometry/Extent', 'esri/SpatialReference', 'esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol', 'esri/graphic']).then(([Extent, SpatialReference, SimpleLineSymbol, Graphic]) => {
    const extent = new Extent(selItem.extent[0], selItem.extent[1], selItem.extent[2], selItem.extent[3], new SpatialReference({wkid: 4326}));
    self.isDrawToolVisible = selItem.useExtent;
    self.selectedItem = selItem;
    const color: any = '#004065';
    const symbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, color, 4);
    self.extentLayer.clear();
    self.extentLayer.add(new Graphic(extent, symbol));
    if (self.cartMap.graphics) {
      self.cartMap.graphics.clear();
    }
    if (selItem.useExtent && selItem.clipGraphic) {
      self.cartMap.graphics.Add(selItem.clipGraphic);
    }


    self.downloadFinishedItems = self.cartService.getItemsFinishedDownload();
  });
}
```

UPDATE :

When I try to center the x and y return with NaN:

[image]

Comment: The extent object has a [center property](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Extent.html#center).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new [Extent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/extent-amd.html) object using your specified parameters. If you omit the Spatial Reference parameter it will default to wkid: 4326. Then call the extent's [getCenter()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/extent-amd.html#getcenter) method to return the center point. Then simply call the map's [centerAt()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#centerat) method passing in the center point. Below is sample code for the 3.x JS API:

```
require(["esri/map", "esri/geometry/Extent"],
    function (Map, Extent) {
        var map = new Map("map", {
            basemap: "topo",
            center: [-106.45, 35.75],
            zoom: 13
        });            
        var extent = new Extent(-106.728864, 35.014214, -106.477219, 35.190922);
        var centerPoint = extent.getCenter();        
        map.centerAt(centerPoint);
   });
```